# counting in directory

Tags: ls, wc

I would like to know what the difference is between:

```
$ ls | wc -l
```

and

```
$ ls > foo
$ wc -l < foo
```

when counting all files in the current directorys. And why does the second one gives me one file more.

Comment: Parsing `ls` output is not a good way to count number of files, perhaps you should start using shell features for this kind of task..

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference, really. The second case would also include the file `foo` in the list and therefore gives you a count of 1 more.

Comment: If there was not a file "foo" already in the directory that is. Re-doing "ls -l" will show the same number as "wc -l < foo".

Comment: @Rinzwind: Good point.

Comment: @Rinzwind `ls -l` also has total number of blocks at the top, that's why it gives additional count. It has nothing to do with file itself

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing with  `ls > foo` is redirecting output of ls to a file. Surprisingly enough, the file is being created first, and included into the output of `ls`

```
   abcd:$ ls                                                                      
a?b  file name

abcd:$ ls > file                                                               

abcd:$ cat file
a
b
file
file name
```

Before redirection , there were two files `a\nb` and `file name`. After redirection : 3 files , `file` included. This is the real problem in your case.

But you probably noticed something else : why is `a\nb` file was listed on two lines. Why ? `ls` can list files, but shell allows almost any type of character in filename, including newline. Thus when output of ls is parsed, there may be erroneous information. For proper counting of files, which is what your main goal is here, you could use `for` loop with shell glob

```
abcd:$ for FILE in * ; do echo "1";done                                                                                               
1
1
1
```

As you can see it correctly shows i have 3 files (including the `file` redirected from before)

For more info , refer to http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html